# creating video file

Tags: visual-c++, wmv, screen-capture

How would I create an class that records the users interactions with the desktop.  and it should  convert it to a video format such as wmv file?

Answer (score 0):

Cam Studio is open source and written in VC++. The source is not too bad either.

http://camstudio.org/

Answer (score 0):

[Windows Media Encoder has this ability](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/CaptureScreenAsVideo.aspx) (CodeProject article 4.66 rating)